# Program returns me always 0

Tags: c++

I have no errors in compilation and no warnings but the program( my vector array ) returns me always 0, why ?

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> recursivite(std::vector<int> const source, int const index, int const length);
void recursiviteFinal(std::vector<int> source, int const index, int const length, std::vector<int> dest);
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myTab  {{ 1, 2, 3, 4,
                                5, 6, 7, 8,
                                9, 10, 11, 12,
                                13, 14, 15, 16,
                                17, 18, 19, 20
                            }};

    std::vector<int> myTab2{{0, 0, 0, 0}};

    myTab2 = recursivite(myTab, 4, 4);

    for (unsigned int i{}; i < myTab2.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << myTab2[i];
}
std::vector<int> recursivite(std::vector<int> const source, int const index, int const length)
{
    std::vector<int> myTab(length);

    recursiviteFinal(source, index, length, myTab);

    return myTab;
}

void recursiviteFinal(std::vector<int> source, int const index, int const length, std::vector<int> dest)
{
    if (length > 0)
    {
        dest[length - 1] = source[index + length - 1];
        recursiviteFinal(source, index, length - 1, dest);
    }
}
```

Someone can tell me how I can 'solve this please ?
Thank's !

Comment: `0` is the return code for successful termination. What do you expect it to return?

Comment: what is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're only modifying a **copy** of the original vector:

```
void recursiviteFinal(..., std::vector<int> dest)
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So when you do this inside the function:

```
dest[length - 1] = source[index + length - 1];
```

it only modifies a copy of the vector that gets destroyed when the function exits.

Solution: pass the vector by [**reference**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to be able to modify the original vector:

```
void recursiviteFinal(..., std::vector<int>& dest)
                                           ~
```

Learn the language before using it.